# Postgresql can not Alter table in schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named "well_all", which is in a schema named "staging", postgresql.
Its data is from a csv, the table doesn't have "id" field. I wanted to add "id" field in the table. So I did:

```
ALTER TABLE staging.well_all ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

But I am getting an error:

> "well_all" is not a table, composite type, or foreign table

So, I'd tried to add "id" field simply:

```
ALTER TABLE staging.well_all ADD COLUMN id INTEGER NOT NULL;
```

But getting the same error, too.
I checked the database exists in that schema. It exists. 
Is this something you faced before? Would you like to help me to solve this problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - sorry. It was a typo. Just updated post.

Comment: This should be working AFAIK.  Are you sure that you are targeting the correct database?  Maybe you are sending these instructions in the context of a different DB, and this is why they are failing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes. I could get data from that table. Only "ALTER" is not working.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Yeah you are right. table name was "well_all_t", not "well_all". But I am not sure how it worked in getting data. I also could get db columns from "information.column_name" table with that table name "well_all". It's strange. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad you found the problem.

Comment: You almost certainly have a view called `well_all` which selects from `well_all_t`. It will be listed in information_schema, its columns will be in `columns`. If you run this command: `SELECT table_type FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'well_all'`, see what it returns - if it's a real table it should say `BASE TABLE`. If it's a view it will say `VIEW`

Comment: @eurotrash Great. I will do it.